# Lag with count in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have a dataframe like this one:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2020-01-01"),
  ("2020-02-01"),
  ("2020-02-01"),
  ("2020-03-01"),
  ("2020-03-01"),
  ("2020-03-01"),
  ("2020-04-01"),
  ("2020-05-01")
).toDF("date")

+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2020-01-01|
|2020-02-01|
|2020-02-01|
|2020-03-01|
|2020-03-01|
|2020-03-01|
|2020-04-01|
|2020-05-01|
+----------+
```

Is there a way to calculate the count of records for previous month like so:

```
+----------+----------------+
|      date|prev_month_count|
+----------+----------------+
|2020-01-01|            null|
|2020-02-01|               1|
|2020-02-01|               1|
|2020-03-01|               2|
|2020-03-01|               2|
|2020-03-01|               2|
|2020-04-01|               3|
|2020-05-01|               1|
+----------+----------------+
```

I can achieve this by deriving another dataframe from the original one, shifting dates, aggregating and joining back to the original dataframe. But I was wondering whether maybe a solution with a combination of `lag` and `count` using windows exists.

## Update

Using `lag` with `count` and windows both with spark sql:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
sql("""select date, lag(count(date) over(partition by date order by date)) over(order by date) as prev_month_count from test""").show(false)
```

and the dataframe API:

```
df
  .withColumn("prev_month_count", lag(count($"date").over(Window.partitionBy($"date").orderBy($"date")), 1).over(Window.orderBy($"date")))
  .show(false)
```

I am getting unexpected results:

```
+----------+----------------+
|date      |prev_month_count|
+----------+----------------+
|2020-01-01|null            |
|2020-02-01|1               |
|2020-02-01|2               |
|2020-03-01|2               |
|2020-03-01|3               |
|2020-03-01|3               |
|2020-04-01|3               |
|2020-05-01|1               |
+----------+----------------+
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that:

1. computes `count` per partition (by month)
2. generates an intermediary column `temp` populated with `null` for all rows except for the first row in each partition, which is assigned the `count` from its previous row
3. backfills `null` values from the last non-null value in each partition via Window function `last`

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy("date")
val w0 = Window.orderBy("date")

df.
  withColumn("count", count("date").over(w)).
  withColumn("temp", when(row_number.over(w) === 1, lag("count", 1).over(w0))).
  withColumn(
    "prev_mo_count",
    last("temp", ignoreNulls=true).over(w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
  ).
  show
/*
+----------+-----+----+-------------+
|      date|count|temp|prev_mo_count|
+----------+-----+----+-------------+
|2020-01-01|    1|null|         null|
|2020-02-01|    2|   1|            1|
|2020-02-01|    2|null|            1|
|2020-03-01|    3|   2|            2|
|2020-03-01|    3|null|            2|
|2020-03-01|    3|null|            2|
|2020-04-01|    1|   3|            3|
|2020-05-01|    1|   1|            1|
+----------+-----+----+-------------+
*/
```

Note that column `date` is assumed to be always the 1st day of the month (as implied in the provided sample data).  In case they consist of arbitrary day values, partitioning should be defined differently, like:

```
Window.partitionBy(date_format($"date", "yyyyMM")).orderBy("date")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid using `groupBy` as I have other columns in my actual dataframe that I want to keep.

Comment: @somethingsomethingdangerzone, in that case, use Window functions over a couple of window specs as shown in my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely ! this can be accomplished ,as you rightly said.

sparkSql way of doing this:

EDIT 1: Updated the query to fix "multiple count values for each date" issue.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

spark.sql("""select date,first(lag(count(date) over(partition by date order by date)) over(order by date)) over(partition by date) as prev_month_count from test""").show(false)

+----------+----------------+
|date      |prev_month_count|
+----------+----------------+
|2020-01-01|null            |
|2020-02-01|1               |
|2020-02-01|1               |
|2020-03-01|2               |
|2020-03-01|2               |
|2020-03-01|2               |
|2020-04-01|3               |
|2020-05-01|1               |
+----------+----------------+
```

If you don't prefer to use sparkSql ,this can be done using dataframe APIs as well.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to do this using the dataframe api for some hours now and I'm just baffled as to why it doesn't work the way I expect it to:
`.withColumn("prev_month_count", lag(count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"date").orderBy($"date")), 1).over(Window.orderBy($"date".asc)))`

Comment: I just noticed that your result is also incorrect - the same dates have different `prev_month_count` values.

Comment: You are right ,there is a flaw in the logic. Apologies for that. Let me try to tweak that !

Comment: I have updated the answer by including a first after lag. May not be the most elegant solution. Please check if this works for you. Also for the dataframe API to work,there is a similar tweak required .                                                       ```df.withColumn("prev_month_count", first(lag(count($"date").over(Window.partitionBy($"date").orderBy($"date")), 1).over(Window.orderBy($"date"))).over(Window.partitionBy($"date"))).show(false)```